# Move schema_migration table to newer version without migrating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-migration

Most of my migrations are by number, not timestamp, but 5 or 6 of them (the most recent) are with timestamp. These I want to move to number based, and now I want to forward the migration table to the appropriate number. How do I force the table to update without actually running the migration, or should I migrate down to 5 or 6 ago (before timestamp) and then migrate up again with numbers?

Comment: You might have done this already, but for future migrations you can switch back to the number prefixes by using this configuration option, config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to edit the corresponding rows in the table by hand, or roll down and back up after renaming. I'm not even sure how the rolling down and up will be handled if the migration numbers are in mixed format.

Comment: when you say edit-by-hand, do you mean remove the timestamp based entries, replace them with their number equivalents, and then it will be ok?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what i meant :)